# How to use VBO data as position data in vertex shader and uniform data as color data in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl

This is my codes,they are converted from the codes in the book “OpenGL Programming Guide”:

```
GLuint VAOs,Buffers;
void init(){
   glGenVertexArrays(1, VAOs);
   glBindVertexArray(VAOs);
   GLfloat vertices[6][2] = {
        {-0.9f,-0.9f},
        {0.85f,-0.90f},
        {-0.90f, 0.85f},
        {0.90f, -0.85f},
        {0.90f,0.90f},
        {-0.85f, 0.90f}
    };
    glGenBuffers(1, Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    ShaderInfo shaders[] = { {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert"},{GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag"} ,{GL_NONE, NULL} };

    program = LoadShaders(shaders); 

    GLuint pos = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vposition");
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);

    GLuint index,b;
    char *name[]={"color"};
    GLfloat fcolor[4]={1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
    glGetUniformIndices(program,1,(const char**)name,&index);
    glGenBuffers(1, &b);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(fcolor), fcolor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, index, b);

    glUseProgram(program);
}
```

this is the vertex shader:

```
#version 430 core
uniform vec4 fcolor;
layout(location=3)in vec4 vposition;
void
main()
{
    vec4 p = vposition;
    gl_Position = p;
}
```

this is the fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core
uniform vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;
void
main()
{
    fColor = color;
}
```

I thought there would be a red triangle on black background ,but in fact there is just a black window. I can't figure out why,help me please!

Comment: Pleas post the original code. What is the actual type of `VAOs` respectively `Buffers`. Either that are arrays or not, but `glGenVertexArrays(1, VAOs)` and `glBindVertexArray(VAOs)` won't work at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uniform vec4 color;` is not a [Uniform block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Block_buffer_binding) (see also [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object)).
It is just a [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variable (within default uniform block). So you've to use [`glUniform*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) to set the value.

```cpp
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform4fv(index, 1, fcolor);
```

An additional fault in your code is that the buffer object which is meant to be the array buffer (`Buffers[ArrayBuffer]`) is bound to the target `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER`. Probably the uniform buffer object is `b`:

<s>`glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);`</s>

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, b);
```

---

Of course you can use a named [Uniform Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). In the example the [Binding point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) is set by a [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)). e.g.:

```c
#version 430 core

layout (std140, binding = 1) uniform UB_color
{
   vec4 color;
};

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = color;
}
```

```cpp
GLuint ubo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ubo);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(fcolor), fcolor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, ubo); // 1 because of 'binding = 1'
```

Respectively if you don't want to set the uniform bock binding by a layout qualifier (for whatever reason):

<s>`layout (std140, binding = 1) uniform UB_color`</s>

```c
layout (std140) uniform UB_color
```

```cpp
GLuint ubo_index = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "UB_color");
GLuint ubo_binding = 7; // arbitrary number
glUniformBlockBinding(program, ubo_index, ubo_binding);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo_binding, ubo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```c
layout(location=3)in vec4 vposition;
```

with

```c
layout(location=3)in vec2 vposition;
```

and also replace

```c
vec4 p = vposition
```

with

```c
vec4 p = vec4(vposition.x, vposition.y, 0.0, 1.0)
```

In this code:

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

You are loading a vertex attribute with a size of 2 floats and then in the shader you are telling it to give 4 floats (Vector4 is just 4 floats in GLSL).

Comment: No wrong. The components are "expanded". The z component becomes 0 and the w component becomes 1. It is perfect valid to specify an attribute with less components than the corresponding attribute variable. See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 10.3.5 Transferring Array Elements, page 360](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=382&zoom=100,0,305)

Comment: The lenth of the vec in shaders dosen't mater.The mistake should be the uniform buffer.